# Webpack fails to import module in parent directory

Tags: webpack

I have a dir structure like so:

```
/src
   /components
     fooComponent.js
     /someDir
        webpack.json
        index.js
        package.json
```

package.json:

```
      "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.22.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.12"
  }
```

`The index json is imported the fooComponent.js like so:`

```
import fooComponent from '../fooComponent'
```

But when running webpack I get this error:

Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "me/src/components

webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./index"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "foo.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'}


    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share webpack config.

Comment: Can you please clean up the file structure also. Is index inside source or outside.

Comment: @sandeep index.js is in someDir

Comment: Try setting context as `__dirname + "../"`. if your webpack config is in `somedir`. And also if index.js is in somedir then it has to be as `import fooComponent from "../components/fooComponent"`. The import path are relative.

Comment: sorry path will be `import fooComponent from "../fooComponent"`.

Answer (score 3):

The webpack config considers that your working directory is defined by context. Your context is set to **someDir**, your component is outside the directory to be transformed by babel and will be treated at a regular javascript file.

Change the configuration to make context point to `src` directory. It will start transforming all the files in your codebase.

Or you can use a `include` tag to include the parent directory to be transformed as well.

Try a structure like this

```
src/
  components/
    fooComponent.js
  someDir/
    otherJsFiles.js
  index.js
webpack.config.js
```

Keep webpack.config out of src as it is a config to build the code and not the code itself. Then in your js loader section add `include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),`.

Your index.js will be an entry point like `entry: "./src/index.js";`

Comment: what should my entry:main be?